# Is it possible to to make this delete button and input form work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So iv been stuck for quite some time now, i need to make my delete button work on every row and make inputs spit info to my table.
My question is : Is it even possible to do it? (I just started to learn react/js literally today).

The final product should look like "to do list" but when i open it it automatically has values from api that i can delete and add new.

My code:

```
 export default class FetchRandomUser extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    people: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const pirmadata = data;
    this.setState({ people: pirmadata.results, loading: false });
   console.log(pirmadata)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>loading...</div>;
    }

    if (!this.state.people.length) {
      return <div>didn't get a person</div>;
    }

    return (

      <div className="listas">
        {this.state.people.map(person => (
          <tr className="taras" key={person.name + person.age}>
            <th className="name">{person.name}</th>
            <th className="birth">{person.birth_year}</th>
            <th className="genders">{person.gender}</th>
            <th><button type="submit" className="delete">Delete</button></th>

          </tr>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My form is made on different .js file and basically is a function which holds this form:

```
<div className="forma">
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name :"></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter birth date :"></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter gender :"></input>
        <button type="submit">Submit entry!</button>
    
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `click` handler for the Delete button that is the `onSubmit` handler of the `form` element. That way when you click it, it will call the form's handler function.

Pass the `handlerFunc` to the component with the th elements as a prop to be able to use it as the following:

```
function YourComponent({ handler }){    
    return <th><button onClick={handler} className="delete">Delete</button></th>);
}
```

Form onSubmit handler:

```
<form onSubmit={handlerFunc}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name :"></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter birth date :"></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter gender :"></input>
        <button type="submit">Submit entry!</button>
</form>
<YourComponent handler={handlerFunc} />
```

Comment: Im really failing to understand how should handler function look like to work. Maybe you or anyone can provide me with link to tutorial or documentation?

Comment: @IgnasJuska Are you still have same issue? You need to learn React and passing props to a React component you define. Yes, you can pass functions as props as well. You can learn those from React official website. After learning those concepts it will make more sense.